# How to run a Google Chrome script on a list of pages and put the results in a sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I have a list of IG hashtags and a script that extracts the min, max and the average number of likes from the top 9 posts of the hashtags, but I have to manually go to the tag page, open up the console, paste the script, and then copy/paste the results over to my sheet. Is there a way I can automate this so it is more efficient? I have no knowledge of code.

This is the script

```
/* Hashtag Data */ 
try {
    var data;
    try {
        data = _sharedData.entry_data.TagPage[0].graphql.hashtag
    } catch(a) {
        throw"Cannot find hashtag page data. Try refreshing this web page (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + R) to clear internal data storage, and run the data code again."
    }
    
    var size = data.edge_hashtag_to_media.count,
    top_posts = data.edge_hashtag_to_top_posts.edges,
    likes = top_posts.map(a => a.node.edge_liked_by.count),
    sum = likes.reduce((a, t) => a + t),
    avg = Math.round(sum/likes.length),
    min = Math.min.apply(null, likes),
    max = Math.max.apply(null, likes);
    console.log(`\n\n\n` + (size ? "" : "This hashtag is BANNED, fyi!\n\n") + "\n\n" + size + "\t" + min + "\t" + avg + "\t" + max + "\n\n")
} catch(a) {
    console.error(`\n\nError: ${a}\n\n`)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Google Chrome script" and by "in a sheet"?

Answer (score 0):

So you probably want to use [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

I a loop for each page. Configuring each the loop parameter can be a challenge so I'll leave that up to you.

You can open of a Spreadsheet/Sheet Like this:

```
const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sh.appendRow('row array')
```

You can assemble you data for each row of the sheet in a flat array as shown below:

```
var dataArray=[sum,min,max,avg];
```

and then use `sh.appendRow(dataArray);`

[Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))